# Remove rows where one column is fully contained in another

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with bank account statements with many files that have to be merged, and then duplicates removed. (See two rows from one of those csv files below.) I can drop many duplicates by comparing date (`Buchungsdatum`) and value (`Gutschrift` or `Belastung`), but I need to compare the text (`Buchungstext`) as well. Some transactions have almost identical rows, except that a few more bits of text are added to `Buchungstext`. Those entries can be treated as identical. Now I am at a loss when it comes down to removing those elements.

For example, here are two rows:

```
Buchungsdatum;Valutadatum;Buchungstext;Währung;Gutschrift;Belastung;
01.02.2021;01.02.2021;"SEPA-Basislastschrift; AMAZON EU S.A R.L., NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND; 555-4543534-54545 Amazon.de X5K97DA33; Mandate Ref eAx9ff7a5; Creditor ID DE99887545; End To End ID: X5K97DA33 AMAZON EU S.A R.L., NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND Info: 555-4543534-54545 Amazon.de X5K97DA33";EUR;;24,82;
01.02.2021;01.02.2021;"SEPA-Basislastschrift; AMAZON EU S.A R.L., NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND; 555-4543534-54545 Amazon.de X5K97DA33; Mandate Ref eAx9ff7a5; Creditor ID DE99887545; End To End ID: X5K97DA33";EUR;;24,82;
```

The first row has this info added to `Buchungstext` column (when compared to second row):

`AMAZON EU S.A R.L., NIEDERLASSUNG DEUTSCHLAND Info: 555-4543534-54545 Amazon.de X5K97DA33`

Now my idea is to find out those rows where the `buchungstext` is fully contained in other row's buchungstext and eliminate them.

Here is how I tried (simplified version, as my example has thousands of rows):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'text': [
            'To be or not to be',   # <= Drop this row, as this info is fully contained in next row!
            'To be or not to be, this is here the question.',
            'Whatever is, is right', # <= Drop this row, as this info is fully contained in next row!
            'Whatever is, is right, said the wise man.'
        ]
    }
)


df_tmp = df.text.apply(
    lambda el: df.text.str.startswith(el))

# Inspecting it, I have this:
#
# ipdb > df_tmp
# 0      1      2      3
# 0   True  False  False  False
# 1  False   True  False  False
# 2  False  False   True  False
# 3  False  False  False   True

# => Can I do something with this?
```

From here on I am at a complete loss.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with two parameters (item and texts list) to check the item is in the text list

Then iterate on text column and check the result of function, if the true, delete item

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'text': [
            'To be or not to be.',   # <= Drop this row, as this info is fully contained in next row!
            'To be or not to be. this is here the question.',
            'Whatever is, is right.', # <= Drop this row, as this info is fully contained in next row!
            'Whatever is, is right. said the wise man.'
        ]
    }
)



def have_copy(item, text_list):
    for text in text_list:
        if (item in text):
            return True
    return False


for i in range(len(df['text'])):
    #get item
    item = df['text'][i]
    #a list of onother texts
    text_list = df['text'].drop(i)
    #remove from dataframe if is in the another texts
    if have_copy(item, text_list):
        df = df.drop(i)
```

Output :
||text|
|:--:|:--|
1|To be or not to be. this is here the question.
3|Whatever is, is right. said the wise man.|